# Best practice for "graphic" if-statments in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Just started converting to MVC from classic ASP and wondering about best practice for if-statements that is used to decide if a HTML-element should be visible or deciding if that or that HTML-element should be visible.

Example:

```
if (type = 1)
{
    <img src="/Content/Images/gray.jpg" />
}
else
{
    <img src="/Content/Images/blue.jpg" />
}
```

I see several options here. 
1. Use if-statements in my views (prefer not to)
2. Use a HTML-helper (will be a lot of helpers = Hard to work with the code)
3. Create HTML-snippets in my controller and pass into my view
4. Work with JavaScript to show/hide element on document load.

The example above if of course a simplification of my problem. Many thanks for the help!

/Mike

EDIT:
Took a bad example, here comes a new:

```
if (type = 1)
{
    <span class="class1">Something something</span>
}
else
{
    <div id="id1">
        text 
        <img src="/Content/Images/gray.jpg" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to use HtmlHelper extensions or declarative HTML helpers for all but most trivial conditional expressions. However in this case I would probably let my laziness win, and express the conditional directly in the view like so:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/@(i == 1 ? "gray" : "blue").jpg" />
```

**Edit**

For more complex scenarios, definitely HTML helpers. If you're using the Razor syntax, you can create declarative helpers by placing them into your ~/Views/Helpers directory. They're very clean to write and use.

But the idea behind creating a good helper is that it encapsulates an *intention*. This is easy to test by trying to give your helper a name. If the name is `IfOneThenShowSomethingElseGrayImage`, you should try to break it into further pieces still.

So let's imagine the intention in your example is to show information about the current user based on the user type. You could create a helper like this:

```
@helper UserType(int type) {
   @if (type == 1) {
    <span class="class1">Something something</span>
   } else {
    <div id="id1">
        text 
        <img src="/Content/Images/gray.jpg" />
    </div>
   }    
}
```

And then use it in your view like this:

```
@UserType(Model.UserType)
```

Even though it's only used on one page, it enhances the readability in the view, and can be reused if necessary.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Ok! How would you then do with the new example I posted? I thought about using HtmlHelpers but started to think, what is best: Have 10 if-statements in my partial view or 10 extra Htmlhelpers which only is used in that specific view...

Comment: I think this makes things worse.  Instead of having all UI in one page you split off logic and somebody then has to search through.  Broadcasting intent is awesome but not when you can't zip around the codebase easily.

Comment: @jfar - I can see how you'd think that. Like I said, just my 2 cents. I usually run highly convention-based projects, so I know that if I'm in view *this*, I'll find the helpers in file *that*. I used to work with classic ASP, so I can't stand code in views :)

Comment: Yeah, each his own I guess.  I'm working on a project where your technique was taken to an extreme level and its really tough to move around.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'm starting to use a separate layer for loading up by viewmodels with html specific information.

```
 public class ViewModel
 {
     public string ImageName { get; set; }
 }
```

Keeps the views clean:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/<%= Model.ImageName %>.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I said the example above is a very simple example. Picture the if-statement to be about showing a <div> or a <span>

Comment: Could also be a statement about showing a <img> and a <p> OR showing nothing. Still quite simple examples if I compare to the actual code I'm working on.  Thanks!

Comment: This example does not break down for more complex matters IMO, that is until the matter becomes so complex that an entirely different view should be served.